# How to fix the issue with proprietary nvidia driver and plymouth on trusty 14.04?

Tags: plymouth, gpu-driver, proprietary, ubuntu-drivers, hacking

I have encountered the following problem:

The xorg-server seems to be slow and crashing after a while on my nvidia quadro fx 4000. Screen freezes but becomes available again, when i make a screenshot and crashes again when I want to dismiss the save screenshot window.

When i go and use the proprietary driver the splash screen becomes ugly (known issue) and none of the fixes helps properly.

Comment: The downvote could be because of poor english / grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing you driver, latest found [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-x-swat):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

OR in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

OR open (found in your applications)

> Additional Drivers

and install an alternative driver.